# Package for integration over non-rectangular region

Tags: r, integral-equations

I want to compute the expected value of a multivariate function `f(x)` wrt to [dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). My problem is "penta-nomial" (i.e 5 variables) so calculating the explicit form of the expected value seems unreasonable. Is there a way to numerically integrate it? Is there some package (e.g in R) that can let me do that? I realize I can solve it using first principle but I want the computation to be really fast.

```
f(x) = \sum_{0,4}(q_i*log(n/q_i))
```

Comment: Why is your region non-rectangular?

Comment: Because the probability distribution is dirichlet and so the constraint that sum of probabilities should be one makes it non rectangular... That correct right?

Comment: I see, this distribution us defined over a simplex (I didn't know that). One option is to use a Gauss quadrature over your simplex,  like [here]( http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9435-n-dimensional-simplex-quadrature).  Also, see this [question] ( http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2013/higher-order-numerical-integration-on-a-triangle-tetrahedron-simplex).

Comment: you could use stochastic integration as long as you knew what the domain was.  Randomly select a point and determine whether it is in the parcel of the integral or not, within the hyper-rectangle.  You know the volume of the hyper-rectangle, and as your point-count gets high enough, you have the ratio of "in" to "out".  Multiply the volume by the ration to get the estimated volume of your sub-parcel.